# My Superset cache is set to Redis, but I still get cache warning in logs

Tags: apache-superset, redis-cache

I am getting cache warnings in my log files and am not sure why.

My cache override:

```
CACHE_CONFIG = {
    'CACHE_TYPE': 'RedisCache',
    'CACHE_DEFAULT_TIMEOUT': 86400,
    'CACHE_KEY_PREFIX': 'superset_',
    'CACHE_REDIS_HOST': 'localhost',
    'CACHE_REDIS_PORT': 6379,
    'CACHE_REDIS_DB': 1,
    'CACHE_REDIS_URL': 'redis://localhost:6379/1'
}
```

I also tried `redis` instead of `RedisCache`

the log statements:

> 2022-05-06 15:03:27,118:INFO:root:Configured event logger of type
> <class 'superset.utils.log.DBEventLogger'> Falling back to the
> built-in cache, that stores data in the metadata database, for the
> following cache: `FILTER_STATE_CACHE_CONFIG`. It is recommended to use
> `RedisCache`, `MemcachedCache` or another dedicated caching backend
> for production deployments 2022-05-06
> 15:03:27,123:WARNING:superset.utils.cache_manager:Falling back to the
> built-in cache, that stores data in the metadata database, for the
> following cache: `FILTER_STATE_CACHE_CONFIG`. It is recommended to use
> `RedisCache`, `MemcachedCache` or another dedicated caching backend
> for production deployments Falling back to the built-in cache, that
> stores data in the metadata database, for the following cache:
> `EXPLORE_FORM_DATA_CACHE_CONFIG`. It is recommended to use
> `RedisCache`, `MemcachedCache` or another dedicated caching backend
> for production deployments

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is a different cache, hence you need an additional configuration, i.e.

```
FILTER_STATE_CACHE_CONFIG = {
    'CACHE_TYPE': 'RedisCache',
    'CACHE_DEFAULT_TIMEOUT': 86400,
    'CACHE_KEY_PREFIX': 'superset_filter_',
    'CACHE_REDIS_URL': 'redis://localhost:6379/2'
}
```

Ensure to use a different prefix and DB

Comment: Remember, you do create this sequence for each cache you require, ending with multiple almost same looking blocks of configure...